# How to open a page from a class?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

I am trying to create a little application using MVVM. I would like to open a second page that scan a QR code and then back the value of the QR code to the main page.

I have this code:

Main view:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="QRScannerXamarinForms.Views.MainPageView"
             xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:QRScannerXamarinForms.ViewModels">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Barcode Sample" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36" />
        </Frame>
        <Button x:Name="ucBtnEscanear" Text="Escanear"
                Command="{Binding EscanearCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Main view model:

```
private INavigationService _navigationService;



public ICommand EscanearCommand { get; private set; }

private void Escanear()
{
    string miCodigoQr = _navigationService.AbrirPaginaEscaner();
}
```

Second view:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="QRScannerXamarinForms.Views.ScannerView"
             xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:QRScannerXamarinForms.ViewModels">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:ScannerViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
                <Label Text="Barcode Sample" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36" />
            </Frame>
            <Label x:Name="ucScanResultText" />
            <zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="ucZXingScannerView" IsScanning="True" IsAnalyzing="True" Result="{Binding CodigoQr}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Second view model:

```
class ScannerViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _codigoQr;

    public string CodigoQr
    {
        get { return _codigoQr; }
        set { _codigoQr = value; }
    }

}
```

Interface to open pages:

```
namespace QRScannerXamarinForms.Services
{
    interface INavigationService
    {
        string AbrirPaginaEscaner();
    }
}
```

Implementation of the interface that allows navigation.

```
namespace QRScannerXamarinForms.Services
{
    class ViewNavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        public string AbrirPaginaEscaner()
        {
            ScannerView miScannerView = new ScannerView();
            ScannerViewModel miScannerViewModel = miScannerView.BindingContext as ScannerViewModel;

            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(miScannerView);

            return miScannerViewModel.CodigoQr;
        }
    }
}
```

But in the implementation of the interface, the second page is not shown. So this line doesn't work:

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(miScannerView);
```

How could I open from this class?

Thanks.

Comment: you're not going to be able to return a value from the navigation method

Comment: Since you want to implement interface `INavigationService` in class `ViewNavigationService ` and returun a string , but why are you putting the `PushModalAsync` code into method `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(miScannerView);` ?  It's weird.

Comment: I put PushModalAsync() because I would like to open a page in this class. The idea it is to have a service that handle all the navigation needs. I thought that if I put this code in codebihind of some page, I would spread the code between this service, the view model and the view.

Comment: `The idea it is to have a service that handle all the navigation needs.` Sorry, I don't quite catch your meaning. Can you elaborate on that？